Is "资治通鉴" still worthy to read now?
I am a native chinese speaker with a fine grasp of ancient language formalisms, so I have no problem in reading 资治通鉴 in 文言文 version. But I haven't read a lot of history books, especially chinese, which I would say I've read nearly none.
My question is: Is it worthy to read 资治通鉴 in my case?
A few reasons for this question:

I am afraid 资治通鉴's ideas could be substituted with modern writings, such as 钱谬's 国史大纲，which even covers more breadth of history then it does.

I haven't read any chinese history books, and I've heard 资治通鉴 concerns quite a short period of time's history, so does it seem not worthy to dig in directly into 资治通鉴?

I don't know what benefits could this reading bring me with.


Thank you in advance for any response.

It is a matter of personal choice. When you want to know whether it (not necessarily reading a book) is worth your trouble or not, you must have a purpose in your mind. From the words you provided above, you seemed to have no idea what your real purpose is.

It provides knowledge of how to rule the Chinese, not in a good way though, but quite effectively. Guess who is exceptionally familiar with this book, among those famous or infamous figures in Chinese modern history?

Although I'm not that good in ancient chinese books, especially those written in 文言文, I can still provide some recommendations. I suggest that you read 史記 first. 史記 covers history from the late 周 to 戰國 times, and into 西漢. It covers a large time period that was full of different events. I've read 史記 before, albeit a simplified version (not in 文言文), and found it very interesting.
